# Impresión Directa de Pdf en Api Net Core C# 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Necesito imprimir directamente a una impresora(Ticketera Termica)un archivo pdf , la accion se realizará desde un cliente (vue js) y la ejecuta el servidor que esta en Net Core C# ,y este tiene conectada la impresora.

Me a sido muy dificil conseguir ,alguna librería o instrucción que lo realice en Net Core 2.1 , Entorno Windows 7 y 10.

**Pregunta**

Como enviar a imprimir un archivo pdf directamente( Imprimir desde el Servidor) en Net Core C#?
Graciad , si no fui especifico o me falta agregar algo , corriganme porfavor , gracias

Comment: Hola. Si quieres imprimir de HTML a PDF en ASP.NET Core, puedes utilizar el plugin **Rotativa.AspNetCore**. Te recomiendo leas este artículo [Cómo crear un PDF a partir de una Vista en ASP.NET Core MVC](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/3/21/c%C3%B3mo-crear-un-pdf-a-partir-de-una-vista-en-aspnet-core-mvc)

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con impresión directa? ¿Enviar el archivo sin previsualización para que sea impreso?

Comment: @RafaelAcosta esto ya lo realizo , creo el pdf mediante rotativa , y ahora quiero imprimirlo , ahi mismo en el servidor

Comment: @fredyfx si ,necesito imprimirlo sin previsualización

Comment: @AntonioGuerrero: Eso ya es más complicado. Si tienes la impresora directamente conectada al servidor como dices en la pregunta, lo lógico sería redirigir ese **response** con el PDF que iría al explorador, hacia el puerto donde está conectada la impresora. Es interesante la pregunta.

Comment: @AntonioGuerrero: Aun así, creo que la idea del archivo PDf no es buena, imprimir un PDF en una impresora térmica no se si será posible. Yo lo haría enviando texto formateado y caracteres de escape al puerto LPT donde está la impresora

Comment: @RafaelAcosta puede ser complicado ..pero tengo la esperanza que sea posible , ya que visto que otros lo realizan , aunque la sitiacion se complica mas siendo .net core , teniendo el pdf podria convertirlo a otro formato.. este me permite tener un control total del diseño y tamaño de la impresion, lo que no tengo con los caracteres de escape

Comment: no es complicado, es enviar un POST con los valores y ya, ese tipo de impresoras tienen un API, ¿revisaste la documentación?